# Joining 2 SQL tables based on IPv4 and IPv6 range

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ip, range, ip-address

First off, sorry if this question has already been asked but I've searched everywhere (including this site) and have found somewhat similar scenarios but no solutions pertaining to IPv6. And the solutions that I've tried to implement just on IPv4 address were very very slow.
I'd like to join 2 tables together based on the IPAddress in table B being in between the range_from and range_to in table A.
This is on SQL Server 2008:

I have 2 tables, 
Table A contains:

1. range_from (varchar)
2. range_to (varchar)
3. country (varchar)

Table B contains

1. IPAddress (varchar)
2. The only field that really matters is IPAddress

So I need to join table A and table B together

```
ON b.IPAddress BETWEEN a.range_from AND a.range_to
```

Which is what my JOIN clause is. For the 3 fields that contain an IP address I've created a function that converts the human-readable address into BIGINT so that the range can correctly be searched:

```
create function [dbo].[IPAddressToInteger](@ip as varchar(15))
returns bigint
as
begin
return (
convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 1)) +
convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 2)) * 256 +
convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 3)) * 65536 +
convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 4)) * 16777216
)
end
```

My solution is not at all efficient and doesn't include IPv6 addresses. I don't work with SQL too often and am surprised that SQL does not contain any IPAddress data types.

What is the best practice in this scenario?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected result?

Comment: Sure, here is a description [here](http://imgur.com/a/1Jzx4)